# Unexpected duplicate rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I am facing an issue where I find duplicate rows in a table with identical values in every column except for the primary key, which is an auto-increment value. The rows in the table represent unique entries with unique values so there is no reason for the values to be identical. In other words the behavior is abnormal.

My difficulty in debugging this issue lies in the fact that this occurs in a production environment that I cannot replicate and to the fact that I am using a third-party data layer to write to the database that I am not fully aware of how it operates internally.

Before I investigate the third-party tool, I would like to know if there is any chance under any circumstances that SQL Server would fail and log the same data two, three, four or more times in table while executing a single command.

The only indications that I have at the moment are some timeouts on the client side and many occurrences of disk activity overload where the Queue Length goes beyond 50. Can poor disk or server performance cause the SQL Server to fail in such a way?

Comment: When you hear hoof beats, think horses, not zebras. Most unintended data duplication is from malformed queries. Start there.

Comment: There's not a lot here we can really offer here apart from ideas either, which aren't going to be on topic for SO. We don't even have any sample data to hazard guesses. Could it be as simple as a user button hitting the submit button/return key? We literally have no idea.

Comment: @Larnu You are right but I avoided going deeper because it is most likely an application-related issue. I just wanted to know if anyone ever had a similar problem. There is no user involvement, data is generated automatically by a service.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know if there is any chance under any circumstances that SQL Server would fail and log the same data two, three, four or more times in table while executing a single command.

No.  But other layers in your application might do that.

> The only indications that I have at the moment are some timeouts on the client side

For instance if a client makes a request, and the request times out after it has succeeded, but before the client has been notified of the success, this can happen.  This is especially common if the request goes through multiple network hops between the client and the SQL Server.

The root cause, though, is might be poor table design:

> I find duplicate rows in a table with identical values in a very column except the primary key, which is an auto-increment value

If it's not valid to have duplicates in every column but the PK, you are missing a unique index or unique constraint.

Comment: I suppose there can be many issues that could cause poor query performance. What troubles me is that the same application/configuration runs in multiple environments for years without any issues and that in that particular production environment it worked fine until a couple of days ago. It was less frequent in the beginning and is more frequent now.

Answer (score 1):

Just to dismiss any misleading assumptions I traced the problem to issues not related to SQL server. Many thanks to @David for being strongly affirmative that SQL server does not have this behavior under any circumstances. It saved me the time from looking at the wrong direction.